# Когда увеличивают размер экрана то footer идет вниз что делать?

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Oswald-Bold;
    src: url(fonts/Oswald-Bold.ttf); 
   }
html{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    font: 18px 'Arial'; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0;
}
.container{
    min-height: 100%; 
     margin: 0 auto;
      display: flex; 
      flex-direction: column;
    }
 
header, aside, footer{
    padding: 15px;
}
header, footer{
    color: #fff; 
    background-color: rgb(34,192,196); 
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
header{
    background-color: rgb(34,192,196);
}
 
main{
    display: flex;
     flex-grow: 1;
     position: relative;
    }
aside{
    flex-basis: 200px; 
    flex-shrink: 0; 
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
     border-right: 2px solid #000;
    }
aside, .row{
    background-color: #ffcc00;
}
 
.content{
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
     flex-grow: 1;
    }
.row{
    padding: 15px;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    }
.text{
    padding: 15px;
    height: 460px;
    overflow: scroll;
         position: relative;
}
footer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #4589B0;
    background-image: url(images/js2.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.headerLink{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 230px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  align-items: : center;
  padding-left: 70px;
  font-size:18px;
  color: rgb(34,192,196);
}
.headerLogo{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  position: static;
  background-image:url('images/Kvasnuk_logo.png');
  background-image:no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
.headerLogo2{
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  position: static;
  background-image:url('images/Kvasnuk_logo.png');
  background-image:no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
div.LeftMain{
        flex-basis: 200px; 
    flex-shrink: 0; 
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
     border-right: 2px solid #000;
    width: 385px;
    height: 595px;
    background: rgb(107,0,125);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(107,0,125,1) 0%, rgba(195,34,191,1) 100%);
}

div.LeftMain > p{
    font-family: Oswald-Bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
div.MainTop{
    background-image: url(images/js.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 1550px;
    height: 160px;  
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}
div.ChildrenTop{
    padding-left:50px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 120px; 
    margin-left: 310px;
    background-color: rgb(34,192,196);
}
div.ChildrenTop > p{
    font-family: Oswald-Bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: rgb(54, 0, 56);
    margin-top: 10px;
}
img {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 320px;
  }

  p.image:after {
    content: attr(image) "(Використання функції attr)";
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    div.ChildrenTop{
        width: 400px;
        height: 80px; 
        
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    div.ChildrenTop{
        width: calc(300px + 100px);     
        height: 80px; 
        
    }
    div.LeftMain{
        width: 450px;
        height:  calc(300px * 5);      
        padding: 10px;
        background: rgb(107,0,125);
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(107,0,125,1) 0%, rgba(195,34,191,1) 100%);
    }
    @media print{

    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div class = "container1"> 
      <div class="MainTop">
      <div class="ChildrenTop"><p>Мова програмування Javascript</p></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="LeftMain">
        <h2 align="center">Основні події:</h2>
        <p>
         &#9675;Дата появи   &#187;1995<br>
         &#9675;Розробник  &#187;Netscape Communications Corporation, Mozilla Foundation<br>
         &#9675;Тестова версія   &#187;27 липня 2010<br>
        </p>
        <p><img src="images/photo.jpg">
        </p>
        <p class="image"></p>
        <p>Брендан Айк - творець Javascript</p>
      </div>
      <section class="content">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="TopRight">
          <p>JavaScript (JS) — динамічна, об'єктно-орієнтована прототипна мова програмування. Реалізація стандарту ECMAScript. Найчастіше використовується для створення сценаріїв вебсторінок, що надає можливість на боці клієнта (пристрої кінцевого користувача) взаємодіяти з користувачем, керувати браузером, асинхронно обмінюватися даними з сервером, змінювати структуру та зовнішній вигляд вебсторінки.</p>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="text">
            Поява в Netscape<br><br>

1995 року компанія Netscape поставила завдання вбудувати мову програмування Scheme чи «якусь схожу» в браузер Netscape. Для цього був запрошений Брендан Айк, американський розробник, що спеціалізувався на системному програмуванні. Також, для прискорення розробки, Netscape почали співробітництво з компанією Sun Microsystems.<br>

З часом, концепція розроблюваної мови програмування була розширена до можливості використання безпосередньо в HTML-коді сторінки. Компанії мали на меті створити мову, що могла зв'язати різні частини вебсайтів: зображень, Java-аплетів, об'єктної моделі документа. Ця мова повинна була стати зручною для вебдизайнерів та некваліфікованих програмістів. Робочою назвою нової мови була Mocha, яка була змінена на LiveScript в перших двох бета-версіях браузера Netscape 2.0. А дещо пізніше, користуючись популярністю бренду Java, LiveScript був перейменований на JavaScript і третя бета-версія (2.0B3) Netscape 2.0 вже вийшла з сучасною назвою. Для цього була придбана відповідна ліцензія у компанії Sun Microsystems, що володіла брендом Java.<br>

1992 року компанією Nombas була розроблена скриптова мова програмування Cmm (англ. С-minus-minus, гра слів навколо мови С++), яка пізніше була перейменована на ScriptEase та могла вбудовуватися в вебсторінки. Існує хибна думка, що JavaScript створено під впливом Cmm. Насправді Брендан Айк ніколи не чув про Cmm до того, як він створив LiveScript[8]. Пізніше, Nombas зупинили розробку Cmm та почали використовувати JavaScript, а згодом брали участь у групі зі стандартизації JavaScript.<br><br>
Стандартизація<br><br>

У листопаді 1996 року Netscape заявила, що відправила JavaScript в організацію Ecma International для розгляду мови як промислового стандарту. В результаті подальшої роботи з'явилась стандартизована мова з назвою ECMAScript. У червні 1997 року, Ecma International опублікувала першу редакцію специфікації ECMA-262. Рік по тому, у червні 1998 року, щоб адаптувати специфікацію до стандарту ISO/IEC-16262, були внесені деякі зміни і випущена друга редакція. Третя редакція побачила світ в грудні 1999 року.<br>

Четверта версія стандарту ECMAScript так і не була закінчена і четверта редакція не вийшла. Тим не менш, п'ята редакція з'явилася в грудні 2009 року.<br>

У червні 2015 року вийшла шоста версія, починаючи з якої комітет ECMAScript прийняв рішення перейти на щорічні оновлення і нова версія отримала назву ES2015. Вона отримала цілу низку нововведень, серед яких: об'єкт Promise для зручного асинхронного виконування коду, деструктуруюче присвоювання, стрілочні функції, функції-генератори, шаблонні рядки, оператори оголошення змінних let та const тощо.<br>

Версія ES2016 вийшла у червні 2016 року, серед нововведень оператор піднесення до степеня ** та метод Array.prototype.includes, який перевіряє, чи міститься переданий аргумент в масиві.<br>

Версія ES2017, що вийшла в червні 2017 року, додала можливість використання асихронних функцій, «висячих» ком в параметрах функцій, об'єкт Atomics, декількох нових методів для роботи з рядками.<br>

Версія ES2018 вийшла у червні 2018 року, додала можливість здійснювати асинхронні ітерації, оператор Spread (...) для роботи з об'єктами та масивами, декілька нових можливостей для регулярних виразів, метод Promise.prototype.finally, який спрацьовує по отриманню Promise'ом статусу "виконаний".<br>

Версія ES2019 вийшла у червні 2019 року, серед нововведень: новий тип даних Symbol, нові методи для роботи з рядками та масивами, перетворення об'єктів в масиви і навпаки за допомогою Entries.<br>

Актуальною на даний момент є версія ES2020, що вийшла у червні 2020 року. Вона додала до мови новий тип даних BigInt, оператор ?? для перевірки на null та undefined, можливість використання опціональних значень в об'єкті, динамічні імпорти, об'єкт globalThis, методи String.prototype.matchAll для пошуку у рядку за допомогою регулярних виразів та Promise.allSettled для спрацювання після виконання усіх Promise'ів.<br><br>
Актуальний стан<br><br>
JavaScript, наразі, є однією з найпопулярніших мов програмування в інтернеті. В перші роки існування, більшість професійних програмістів скептично ставилися до мови, цільова аудиторія якої складалася з програмістів-аматорів. Поява AJAX змінила ситуацію та звернула увагу професійної спільноти до мови, а її подальші модифікації за стандартами ES6+ внесли багато корисних можливостей, яких не вистачало для ефективного програмування. В результаті, були розроблені та покращені багато практик використання JavaScript (зокрема, тестування та налагодження), створені бібліотеки та фреймворки, поширилося використання JavaScript поза браузером.<br>

        </div>
      </section>  
          </main>
          <footer>
      <div class='headerLogo'></div>
      <div class="headerLink"><a href="https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML">&#8258;HTML&#8258;</a></div>
      <div class="headerLink"><a href="https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS">&#8258;CSS&#8258;</a></div>
      <div class="headerLink"><a href="https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript">&#8258;JAVASCRIPT&#8258;</a></div>
      <div class='headerLogo2'></div>
    </footer>    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите, чтобы футер прилипал к "ботому" блока с текстом - его нужно указать в блоке с текстом, причем под "блоком с текстом" я имею ввиду `

```html
<div id="parent" style="релативе">
  <div id="text"><div>
  <footer style="абсолюте"></footer>
 </div>
```

Для `position: absolute` "Координаты top/bottom/left/right для нового местоположения отсчитываются от **ближайшего позиционированного родителя**".
У вас же в коде элемент с `position: relative` даже не является родителем для футера с `position: absolute`. Как футер поймет относительно *чьего* `bootom` ему нужно быть `0`?

https://jsfiddle.net/xcykg076/

Comment: тогда мне текста дать или чему?

Comment: .container{
   position: relative;
 } footer {
 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

Comment: В моем ответе ссылка на песочницу там представлен упрощенный ваш вариант и тот вариант, который, как мне кажется, вам нужен.

Comment: оно чего-то все равно не работает

Comment: 100 процентов расширение-https://ibb.co/19HsQ5g,90 процентов расширениеhttps://ibb.co/82kv5tR
Сам код:https://jsfiddle.net/xjz5wsme/1/